# Blurry close-up shots with rear camera on iPhone 14 Pro on web

Tags: javascript, iphone, web, camera, focus

I'm currently working on web development and using the camera on my device. I've noticed that the rear camera on my iPhone 14 Pro doesn't automatically focus properly when taking close-up shots, especially when using it on the web. Here are some actual screenshots I took while testing with my iPhone 14 Pro:

[image: 1]

For comparison, here are the results of using the same code on an iPhone 12:

[image: 2]

I was wondering if anyone has dealt with a similar issue. I haven't been able to find any relevant solutions online, but I have seen some people resolving this issue on other web applications, so I'm hoping there might be a way to fix this.

Here's the source code I used for testing:

```
<body>
    <div id="contentainer">
      <div class="title">get divce camera and show video</div>
      <div class="video-button">
        <button id="start">start</button>
        <button id="stop">stop</button>
      </div>
      <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
      <select class="midia-list-select"></select>
    </div>

    <script>
      const constraints = {
        video: true,
      };

      function inferFacingModeFromLabel(label) {
        if (label.toLowerCase().includes("back")) {
          return "environment";
        } else if (label.toLowerCase().includes("front")) {
          return "user";
        } else {
          return "environment";
        }
      }
      function inferFacingModeFromCapabilities(capabilities) {
        if ((capabilities?.facingMode?.indexOf("user") ?? -1) >= 0) {
          return "front";
        } else if (
          (capabilities?.facingMode?.indexOf("environment") ?? -1) >= 0
        ) {
          return "back";
        } else {
          return undefined;
        }
      }

      function midiaOnSelect() {
        const midiaList = document.querySelector(".midia-list-select");
        const midiaId = midiaList.value;
        navigator.mediaDevices
          .getUserMedia({
            video: {
              deviceId: {
                exact: midiaId,
              },
            },
          })
          .then((stream) => {
            console.log(stream);
            const video = document.getElementById("video");
            video.srcObject = stream;
          });
      }

      function getMidiaVideoList() {
        function createMidiaOption(device, facingMode) {
          const option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = device.deviceId;
          option.text = `${facingMode.facingModeFromapabilities}|${facingMode.facingModeFromLabel}------${device.label}`;
          return option;
        }

        navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(async (devices) => {
          console.log("divices", devices);
          devices.forEach((device) => {
            console.log("divice", device);

            if (device.kind === "videoinput") {
              navigator.mediaDevices
                .getUserMedia({
                  video: {
                    deviceId: {
                      exact: device.deviceId,
                    },
                  },
                })
                .then((stream) => {
                  const track = stream.getVideoTracks()?.[0];

                  const capabilities = (
                    track?.getCapabilities ?? (() => undefined)
                  ).bind(track)();
                  console.log(capabilities);
                  const midiaList =
                    document.querySelector(".midia-list-select");
                  const facingModeFromLabel = inferFacingModeFromLabel(
                    device?.label
                  );
                  const facingModeFromapabilities =
                    inferFacingModeFromCapabilities(capabilities);

                  midiaList.appendChild(
                    createMidiaOption(device, {
                      facingModeFromapabilities,
                      facingModeFromLabel,
                    })
                  );
                });
            }
          });
        });
      }

      window.onload = async function () {
        const start = document.getElementById("start");
        const stop = document.getElementById("stop");
        const midiaList = document.querySelector(".midia-list-select");

        start.addEventListener("click", () => {
          midiaOnSelect();
          video.play();
        });
        stop.addEventListener("click", () => {
          video.pause();
        });
        midiaList.addEventListener("change", midiaOnSelect);

        const video = document.getElementById("video");

        const media = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          video: true,
        });

        media.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
          track.stop();
        });

        getMidiaVideoList();
      };
    </script>
 </body>
```

Thank you all in advance for your answers and suggestions. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1):

I do agree that just selecting "environment" the iphone should automatically switch to the appropiate camera according to how close you are to the subject without any other code intervention. Hope they fix it soon so it works identically to previous iphone models.

Theres a way of solving it:
You can enumerate the devices and iterate through them (as you are already doing). Then you can select the device id according to the specific label of the camera you want to use. I tested this code and every camera on the iphone 14 pro max is being listed, each one with its respective label and id. My devices are labeled in spanish (since thats the language my iphone is configured), i dont know how they are specifically labeled in english so i cant help you with the specific label name. You should search for a label that contains the word "macro" (or similar, again i didnt test this in english). Then grab the associated device id and pass it to get user media constraints.
If no label matches you can stick to default behaviour (probably for devices different than the iphone 14)

Just use this simple code and make it run in your iphone browser, you will see that labels for the cameras are not just "back", or "environment" or "user", they do contain the specific name of each of the cameras.

```
navigator.mediaDevices
.enumerateDevices()
.then((devices) => {
  devices.forEach((device) => {
    alert(`${device.kind}: ${device.label} id = ${device.deviceId}`);
  });
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error(`${err.name}: ${err.message}`);
});
```

Comment: How do you "make it run in your iPhone browser"?